# Pass a variable of javascript from view to a controller and save in another variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to know if it a way to pass a variable of javascript to a controller. What I'm trying to do is to have a variable in my controller that starts empty when the user sign in and in my view I will validate if the variable is empty or not, if it's empty a call a javascript prompt, where i save the text that I write in a javascript variable, but i don't know how to pass the text to my controller variable.
 This is what i'm trying in code:

The controller:

```
 ViewData["Contenedor"] = contenedor;
```

I pass the variable to the ViewData in the view and validate if is empty or not.If its empty a call the prompt:

```
@if (ViewData["Message"] == null){
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
        var contenedorID = prompt("Ingrese ID del Contenedor a Ingresar", "");
        -- Here I want to do something to pass my variable contenedorID to my controller variable contenedor ---
    };
</script>
```

Comment: how do you want to cal the next controller action? via  a redirect ? then pass via querystring. If you do not want to redirect, you can post via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (ViewData["Message"] == null){
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
        var contenedorID = prompt("Ingrese ID del Contenedor a Ingresar", "");
        -- Here I want to do something to pass my variable contenedorID to my controller variable contenedor ---

@ViewData["Message"] = "variablevalue you want to pass"

    };
</script>
```

This is storing data in viewdata which will be accessible in the controller when you post back.This works with out changing any of your existing code.

The cleaner way would be to do a ajax post or set the value in a hidden variable using @Html.HiddenFor as others have suggested.